# Legal action regarding a potentially violent neighbor

Tags: criminal-law

My neighbor that lives in the apartment below mine repeatedly makes ridiculous complaints of us making noise which include "being able to hear our fan" while we use it during a hot summer night, or that we are "talking too loud" when we are talking at a normal volume in our own rooms. It it important to note that his roommate has no issues with our supposed noise, just him.

A conversation with him last night began with him hammering loudly on our door with his fist and ended in him punching our door before storming off, and given that he seems to have very little control of his anger, my roommates and I are worried he might physically lash out. Given that he did not punch the door hard enough to leave physical evidence, what legal action can we take against a potentially violent neighbor to ensure the safety of my roommates and myself? Can this be considered a form of harassment?

**Edit**: I sent an email to the management company regarding his behavior informing them that I wanted it on record that I notified them in case something happens again and nothing was done on their part. But since "he complained first" we are in jeopardy of being evicted, because if he complains again we would be in violation of our lease agreement (which states we cannot annoy, disturb, inconvenience, or interfere with the quiet enjoyment of another tenant).

I looked up the noise laws for my city, and they state that the noise must be loud for a "reasonable" person of "average sensitivity." I definitely feel that my neighbor does not meet either of these criteria, but is there a way to go about showing this?

Comment: Have you talked to the landlord? Odds are there have been other problems with this tenant.

Comment: @Patrick87 Yes but the fact that "he complained first" I guess trumps our desire for a safe environment. We have just been informed that his most recent complaint has caused us to violate our lease agreement and we were threatened with eviction.

Comment: How did his most recent complaint violate your lease agreement?  You have a right to do normal things in your apartment.  If he is unreasonably sensitive to the sounds of your normal activity that is his problem.  If your landlord claims you're in violation, what provision are you in violation of, and what have you done to violate it?  His behavior is certainly harassment if it persists.  Next time he does something like that, call the police.

Comment: In the lease it mentions keeping quiet hours between 10 p.m. and 8 a.m., and he has conplained that we are making noise during those hours.

Comment: Where are you? You need to look up your jurisdictional law for PFH (protection from harassment), which some jurisdictions have, while other's only have (PFA's) protection from abuse. Obviously, a PFA doesn't suit your circumstances...that is really pertaining only to domestic violence/stalking/physical bullying and usually requires physical violence or eminent threat of same.

Comment: Also, send a certified letter to your landlord explicitly outlining every single instance of harassment. That way they can't ignore it.

Comment: @gracey209 if the landlord attempts eviction under the "they complained first" doctrine, can the tenant also pursue the landlord for harassment?  Tenants generally have better protections against landlords than against other tenants, don't they?

Comment: @phoog, it depends. Where I live is a "renter's rights state" so here you would havre more rights; other places I have lived are "landlord rights states" and there, not so much. It is heavily dependent on your local laws. The landlord, if they want you out, can usually get you out. You cannot really stop it, except to force an eviction rather than going quietly. if you have a lease you can fight it, but if the neighbor is going to testify that you are infringing on their right to quiet enjoyment of their property, you will lose.

Comment: You should find out if there were other tenants there that this person complained about. If you are a minority, and you think this is a ruse to discriminate, you can use that as a defense. At the end of the day though, whether your go by eviction or at the leases end (he won't renew) you will be out one way or another. It's probably better off to negotiate w/ landlord if he ends up telling you to leave, for some time to find a place and maybe some fees for moving you think you could win the hearing.

Comment: @gracey209 In New York City at least, it is quite unlikely for a landlord to be able to get a tenant out just because the landlord wants the tenant out.  There are several cases in which tenants have prevailed in the face of noise complaints from neighbors.  Both the upstairs tenant and the downstairs tenant have a right to quiet enjoyment, after all, and it is possible to rebut a neighbor's testimony.

Comment: Those cases are evictions, and typically public housing or rent controlled. Idk your situation, but a private rental can always elect not renew your lease. That's why u said, it's up to you to decide if you want to go thru the eviction process if they're not going to renew anyway. If there is no lease, a rental agreement can terminate with as little as 39 days notice. Depending on your situation, you may just need to move. It. The rules are dif detergent for different types of rentals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short Answer

> **I would take a two prong approach.**
>
> 1. Prioritize safety first.
> 2. Then get evidence.

#### Safety

Firstly, regarding the safety issue, I would get some form of ***judicial order*** of restraint (e.g., restraining order, order of protection, no contact order, etc. depends on jurisdiction.) Often times you can just go down to the courthouse and obtain a Temporary Restraining Order ***ex parte*** (without notice to the restrained party) and ***pro se*** (without counsel) on the same day.

You just need to fill out some forms and swear a statement before the commissioner in my jurisdiction. There are even people at the courthouse who will help guide you through the procedure (mostly volunteers for Domestic Violence prevention). A permanent restraining order can come later. But this should at least address the issue of the counterparty showing up at your door. If he does so after you get a restraining order (and have him ***served*** with it), you can call the police and have him arrested for violating the restraining order even if he does nothing else wrong.

#### Evidence

Secondly, I would build a legal case. [If you search google for the term ***decibel meter*** you will see that you can purchase one for about $70-$80](https://www.google.com/search?q=decibel%20meter). (Or there are probably some phone apps you can download too.) You might want to get one, then measure the decibel levels next time your neighbor complains or just in general.

Record on video the measurement in various rooms of the apartment then compare that to what the law says. If you are under the threshhold then your evidence would be the video and (maybe, if you can swing it) the testimony of his roommate. Although since he's the roommate and has to live with the guy that might be an iffy proposition.

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you very much :).

Comment: In New York, at least, it's not possible to get a restraining order just like that.

Answer (score -3):

The neighbor shall not assault you.  Open the door and tell her to take up noise complaints with the Landlord, not directly with you.  If your neighbor then assaults you, call the police and report the assault.

Note: Assault = Intentionally putting another person in reasonable apprehension of an imminent harmful or offensive contact.  **No intent to cause physical injury needs to exist, and no physical injury needs to result.**

*This is not legal advice.*